# What programming language and technologies can you advise to use in my project?

Tags: java, php, mysql

It is necessary to create a web-project in which it will be possible to replenish database of clients, to perform different operations with information on the client (delete, add, edit), data reading from database and formation of WORD documents(.doc) according to a template. Calendar with payment of clients. Bonus system. And also further, that the client had opportunity to register and add/update the data. And so on.

---

Perhaps in the future access to data management through mobile applications

---

What languages and technologies of programming to use?

---

On one's mind a linking of

- **PHP (slim framework) + MySQL**
- or
- **Spring Framework + MySQL**

---

- Database: MySQL or ???
- REST API: **php (slim framework)** or **java (spring framework)** or ???
- Front End: **php (slim framework)** or **java (spring framework)** or ???

What can you advise? What are you recommend to use in back end for create REST API? And what do you recommend to use in front end?

Comment: imho, this question is off topic to this site. usr node.js + mongodb. or better: use perl;

Comment: Probably offtopic, but look also into [HOP](http://hop.inria.fr), [Ocsigen](http://ocsigen.org/), [OPA](http://opalang.org/) since all are able to *easily* mix browser side & server side computations. See also [this answer](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/279861/40065) & [Haxe](http://haxe.org/)

Answer (score 2):

Advantages Spring Framework

1. Greate security
2. Easy packaging And distribution
3. You can make an installer (any can install your software)

Advantages php Framework

1. Easy bugs fixes (you don't need to re-package the software, just replace the fixed file)
2. Quickly instalation

I would tell you:

If you need a greate security of the code maybe is better option spring

If You system will be used from a browser i use php

Bouth are good languages and I think the most importante is good practices of programation.
In bouth case I use MVC

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest you to go with php framework [codeigniter!](http://www.codeigniter.com/). It is a popular MVC. You can build huge application on the top of it with less effort.